# College Linear algebra: Given two determinants with 2 columns unknown solve for another determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Hey I have been stuck on this question for quite some time:

Given: $$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
 a  & 1 & d \\ 
 b & 1 & e \\ 
c &1  & f
\end{bmatrix}\qquad  \text{ and }\qquad\det(A)= -4,
$$

$$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
 a  & 1 & d \\ 
 b & 2 & e \\ 
c &3  & f
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad  \text{ and }\qquad\det(B)= -1,
$$

$$C= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a  & 3 & d \\ 
 b & 3 & e \\ 
c &3  & f
\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
D= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 a  & -1 & d \\ 
 b & 0 & e \\ 
c &1  & f
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What is $\det C$? $\det D$?

Right from the go, I can see that $C$ is a scalar of $A$ by $3$ and I know that $\det C= k\,\det A$ but I dont know if I stand corrected.

Furthermore I tried to expand A into :

$$-1 \begin{bmatrix}
b &e \\
c&f
\end{bmatrix} +1\begin{vmatrix}
a &d \\
c&f
\end{vmatrix} -1\begin{bmatrix}
a &d \\
b&e
\end{bmatrix} = -2$$

and B into

$$ 1 \begin{bmatrix}
b &e \\
c&f
\end{bmatrix} -2\begin{vmatrix}
a &d \\
c&f
\end{vmatrix} +3\begin{bmatrix}
a &d \\
b&e
\end{bmatrix} = -1$$

Which results in A being in :
$$-1(bf-ce)+1(af-cd)-1(ae-bd) = -2$$
and B being in

$$1(bf-ce)-2(af-cd)+3(ae-bd) = -1$$

I have no idea what to do from here.. can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Well spotted. Indeed, $\det(C) = 3\det(A)$. Also note that $(-1,0,1) = (1,2,3) - 2\cdot (1,1,1)$.

Comment: Sorry det A should be -4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,
$$
\det C=3\det A=-12.
$$
For $D$, they want you to use that the determinant is linear on a fixed column (or row, but you need column here). Since
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} =-2\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix},
$$
you have that
$$
\det D=-2\det A+\det B=7.
$$

Comment: Where did you pull the -2 out from? Why is it set up like this?

Comment: Also i thought  det(A+B) != det(A)+det(B)

Comment: The coefficients are those needed so that the second column of $D$ is a linear combination of the second columns of $A$ and $B$. And yes, it is not true in general that $\det(A+B)=\det A+\det B$; but that's not what I'm using, since $D\ne -2A+B$.